# stored procedure to calculate 10% quota of leaves for every department daily

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

in a company, there are various department eg,
dept A has 300 employees 
Dept B has 150 Employees
Dept C has 400 employees
Dept D has 50 Employees

need a stored procedure to calculate only 10% leave's allowed to the per department daily .... if employee apply for the leave in php form,
he will get error message saying, 10% quota of leaves full for this particular day, try and apply for some other day

Comment: Do you have a table for the employees, and another for the leaves? Can you provide some data samples?

Comment: To expand on what @RToyo has said - can you also provide examples of what you have done to attempt to do this? That which has failed

Comment: Explain further please?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give an answer without knowing what your table schemas are, but if we assume that you have an `employee` table that contains an employee ID and a department, and a `leaves` table that has the employee ID and the date of their leave, then it is pretty simple to get the percentages.

Here is a query that will get you the percentage of people on leave for a given day, and you can modify it to return what you actually need. You essentially do an `outer join` of the employee table to the leaves table. Wherever there is no matching employee in the leaves table, the columns from that table will be null, and you'll be able to count the non-nulls to determine how many employees are on leave. Then group it by department to get the percentage per department.

```
select
    e.department,
    count(e.employee_id) as employees,

    -- Use a case statement to determine if the employee is on leave. 
    sum(case when (l.employee_id is null) then 0 else 1 end) as leaves,

    -- Note that when dividing two ints, the result will be an int as well. Convert one value to float so that it returns a float.
    sum(case when (l.employee_id is null) then 0 else 1 end) / convert(float, count(e.employee_id)) as percent
from
    employee e,
    left outer join leaves l
        on (e.employee_id=l.employee_id and l.leave_date = 'June 1, 2018')
where
    e.department = 'IT' -- You can specify the department, or leave it out to list all departments
group by
    e.department
```

Comment: When you have a left join and a where predicate for the same table you have logically turned the left join into an inner join. For those types of things you should move the predicate to the join instead of the where clause. But a very noble effort given nearly zero details.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for pointing that out, that was a dumb oversight on my part. The answer has been corrected.

Comment: Hardly what I would call dumb. I applaud your efforts at blindly providing a solution. It might even be somewhat close to what they wanted. :)